# Is showing thanks via serial upvoting acceptable?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

> Thanks for your answer. Because I gave the bounty to other answer I will upvote other answers of yours in this site.

Can we do something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Votes on answers (or questions) should be votes on answers (or questions) - upvoting or downvoting answers because of their authors instead of their content defeats the whole purpose of voting.

Comment: What should I do if I find such comments?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel reply to let the poster know that this sort of thing is not okay. Beyond that, you _could_ flag for mod attention, and we'll figure out if anything else needs to be done.

Comment: Thank you! I am on for it now.

Comment: I would add to this answer that the non-okayness of doing this depends on degree. If you find a good answer, and you go to the author's profile to look at a few of their other posts, and you honestly happen to think those posts are good and worthy of being upvoted, and you upvote them because of that, that's no problem. The key factors that make it okay are (1) that you only vote on posts which deserve to be voted that way because of their content, not because of their author and (2) that you don't vote on too many posts by the same author in a short time.